# Why mention Shabbat at Yom Tov havdalah?

Tags: words, yom-tov, havdalah, motzei-shabbos

Shabbat and Yom Tov share the same text of havdalah (the main bracha), both in davening and with wine. It all makes sense for *Motzei Shabbat*, but why do we mention המבדיל בין יום השביעי לששת ימי המעשה (Who separates between the seventh day and the six days of creation) after Yom Tov?

Comment: Shabbos is considered the archetype of kedusha vs chol.

Comment: Why do we mention light and dark even when doing it without a candle?

Answer (score 2):

To flesh out andrewmh20's comment on the question, the Gemara ([Chulin 26b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=26b&format=pdf)) asks this and answers סדר הבדלות הוא מונה - we're giving the standard list of "divisions" mentioned in the Torah. As Rashi explains there, a division בין יום השביעי לששת ימי המעשה indeed isn't mentioned in those words in the Torah, but it is a suitable lead-in to the end of the bracha, המבדיל בין קודש לחול, since it is that kind of division.