# Ata Chonantanu when Yom Tov is Monday or Thursday

Tags: yom-tov, havdalah

The last line of אתה חוננתנו is:

> אבינו מלכנו החל עלינו הימים הבאים לקראתנו לשלום חשוכים מכל חטא ומנקים מכל עון ומדבקים ביראתך

How does it make sense to say הימים הבאים after Shabbos when Yom Tov is Monday, or after Yom Tov when it's Thursday?  In those cases, there's only one day of חול coming.

Comment: Where does it say "Chol" in that line?

Comment: @DoubleAA החל עלינו implies that the days are חול

Comment: Why? החל just means begin.

Comment: @DoubleAA Really?  I always thought it came from lashon חול.  I guess you're right, היום הזה אחל תת פחדך ויראתך.

Comment: Same root as תחילה.

Comment: Even IF the translation would be "weekday", I'm not seeing the problem. Even "Hol Hamo'ed" is a partial weekday. I get the possible argument that if there was just Friday, which is 1 day, why is the prayer stated in plural form? That would seem to be a weak argument, anyway.

Comment: A better question would be why this paragraph says "Yom Hashvi'i" - the seventh day if you are saying this on any other day besides M. Shabbat.

Comment: @DanF yeah, it's the plural that strikes me.  For the other point http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64215/11532 - although the answer there isn't directly for ata chonantanu

Comment: Thanks for the link to answer my 2nd question. Though, I think I have to look at the Gemarah to better understand the answer, there.

Answer (score 1):

The Art Scroll siddur translates this as

> Our Father, Our King, begin for us the days approaching us for peace

This includes all the days that follow, no matter what they are (including Yom Tov). For example, we say this on Shabbos Chol Hamoed as well even though the following days are not *chol* but *chol hamoed*.

Comment: I guess what prompted me is we don't say this line in ותודיענו, so apparently it doesn't apply to Yom Tov.  (plus a mistaken understanding of החל)